# ¿Como puedo crear un centro de gravedad en unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity, unity2d

¡Hola!, Estoy creando un juego, Y tengo una esfera que esta en el punto (0,0,0), Entonces tengo otra esfera a el lado de esta, El problema esta en que quiero hacer que todos los objetos tiendan a irse hacia el punto (0,0,0), Respetando las fisicas de los rigidbodies y demas, Por poner un ejemplo, Como en Super mario galaxy, He estado buscando pero realmente no encuentro una respuesta que me sirva.

Comment: Hola. Pues realmente creo que es mejor que busques información en inglés y en foros. Un ejemplo es el siguiente http://bit.ly/2pu9MhP

Comment: @Gibrán podrías responder formalmente con código :P

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, Unity tiene un componente en physics2D que se llama PointEffector, Ya solo se trata de jugar con este componente y añadirselo a los objetos que queramos que tengan gravedad, Aqui les dejo la documentación. [Documentación](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PointEffector2D.html)